# Can I give an app the permission to see my calls without allowing to read all my notifications?

Tags: calls, permissions, privacy, mi-band-2

I bought one of these cheap smartwatches (Xiaomi Mi Band 4c). To use it, I need to install the Xiaomi Wear app.

I really like the option to notify me when I get a call. This way I keep my phone in silent during work. But the app demands a **Super Permission to read all my notifications**. This would include bank transactions, personal whatsapp message, etc.

I don't trust Xiaomi that much to give them all that data. Does anyone would have a workaround? I want the app to be able to read my calls but not my notification.

You can see the description in: Settings -> Apps -> Advanced -> Special Apps Access -> Notification access -> select any app.

PS: I do have root access on the phone.

Comment: If you use a bank who's notifications can be accessed that way - CHANGE BANKS NOW!!

Comment: Further you might wish to give [Gadgetbridge](https://codeberg.org/Freeyourgadget/Gadgetbridge) a try. The app is fully FOSS and does not even have network access, so it won't "call home". It's available via [F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/), a place where you get only FOSS apps. So count this comment as 2 recommendations in 1 :) And you then can most likely ditch that Xiaomi app. I'm using Gadgetbridge for years and am quite happy with it.

Comment: https://github.com/mirfatif/PermissionManagerX/blob/master/README.md

Comment: If the app refuses to work without having "Notification Access", I don't think you can do anything about it. Stop using the app and go for a privacy friendly alternative as Izzy suggested. // @alecxs Notification Access is not a (manifest or AppOp) permission. So it cannot be revoked, unfortunately. Enabled notification listener apps are saved in `/data/system/notification_policy.xml` and Secure Settings.